# How to run image_proc with roslaunch

Tags: ros, roslaunch, rosrun, image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you write a launch file to pipeline a color usb camera into image_proc, convert it to mono, and display it in a window?

To display a color usb webcam, this simple launch file works well:

webcam_color.launch:

```
<launch>
  <node name="usb_cam" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen" >
    <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video1" />
    <param name="image_width" value="640" />
    <param name="image_height" value="480" />
    <param name="pixel_format" value="mjpeg" />
    <param name="camera_frame_id" value="usb_cam" />
    <param name="io_method" value="mmap" />
  </node>
  <node name="image_view" pkg="image_view" type="image_view" respawn="false" output="screen">
    <remap from="image" to="/usb_cam/image_raw" />
    <param name="autosize" value="true" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

However, I can't find any examples of using image_proc in a launch file. I can pipe the color video stream into image_proc and display the mono using:

```
roslaunch mypkg webcam_test.launch
ROS_NAMESPACE=usb_cam rosrun image_proc image_proc
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/usb_cam/image_mono
```

What would be the equivalent of doing this all in a single launch file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208724/how-to-run-image_proc-with-roslaunch/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2015-05-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the `node` tag in `roslaunch` xml format allows a `ns`, i.e. namespace, attribute:

[wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node#Attributes](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node#Attributes)

i think

```
ROS_NAMESPACE=usb_cam rosrun image_proc image_proc
```

would be something like

```
  <node name="image_proc" pkg="image_proc" type="image_proc" ns="usb_cam"/>
```

in a launch file.

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7